# How can I handle multiple dependent requests in a saga?

Tags: javascript, axios, redux-saga

I'm trying to make two request, one to save an image an other to save a product with the url from obtained from the first requests

This is what I want to do
first: save product image (I'm using axios for requests)
second: get the url from 'productImage' and then include it in the params to save

this is my code

```js
function* createProduct(action) {
  const { endpoint, params } = action.payload;
  try {   

    const productImage = yield call(new api().createImage, { endpoint, params });

     // I need to wait the url of the image and include it on the params for the second request before is executed
    // E.g. params.image = productImage.url
    const product = yield call(new api().createProduct, { endpoint, params });

    yield put({
      type: CREATE_PRODUCT_SUCCEED,
      payload: {
        product 
      }
    });
  } catch (e) {
    yield put({
      type: CREATE_PRODUCT_FAILED,
      payload: {
        ...e
      }
    });
  }
}

export default function* createProductWatcher() {
  yield takeEvery(CREATE_PRODUCT_EXECUTION, createProduct);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best pattern here is to split your saga (`createProduct`) into two separate sagas:

- `createImage` - will handle the image creation for the product
- `createProduct` - will handle the product creation with the given image

```js
// Creates the product image
function* createImage(action) {
    const { endpoint, params } = action.payload;
    try {
        const image = yield call(new api().createImage, { endpoint, params });
        yield put({
            type: CREATE_IMAGE_SUCCEED,
            // Here you pass the modified payload to createProduct saga
            payload: {
                endpoint,
                params: { image: image.url }
            }
        });
    } catch(e) {
        yield put({
            type: CREATE_IMAGE_FAILED,
            payload: {
                ...e
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```js
//Creates the product with the image
function* createProduct(action) {
    const { endpoint, params } = action.payload;
    try {
        const product = yield call(new api().createImage, { endpoint, params });
        yield put({
            type: CREATE_PRODUCT_SUCCEED,
            payload: {
                product
            }
        });
    } catch(e) {
        yield put({
            type: CREATE_PRODUCT_FAILED,
            payload: {
                ...e
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then use the builtin `yield*` operator to compose multiple Sagas in a [sequential way](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/SequencingSagas.html).

```js
// Another saga for chaining the results
function* invokeSagasInOrder(sagas) {
    try {
        const image = yield* createImage();
        yield* createProduct(image);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your help. This worked for me as I expected and help me to finish my task.